# exporting the html table to excel sheet with a table title or a heading

Tags: reactjs, excel, html-table, export, spreadsheet

I want to export the HTML table with the title above the table but I didn't find any solution to that problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvcHa.png)
the HTML table looks like this and some more.

I used this library

```
react-html-table-to-excel
```

it only did a single table and I also have two table to export in the single excel sheet from the same webpage.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control on the data that you want in your excel sheet then you can use a library called [SheetJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx). You can add/remove columns, change header names, change sheet names and excel file names etc.

In your case if you want to add the data from other tables in one sheet then simply club different array lists into one list before passing the data into XLSX.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).